# ASP.NET Core MVC field value converted to collection instead of string on form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 and have a form with two textboxes. When posting the form, I expect the text values to bind to my view model but they do not.

When I inspect the FormCollection, I can see that the string values are there but appear to be in the form of a collection instead of a plain string. For example if I hover over the field value it says:

```
{test} count: 1
```

I compared this result to another project (ASP.NET Core MVC 3) where I do not have this issue and the value is posted as "test" (expected).  I examined the input tag that is rendered and nothing seems off. I don't know if there is a library that was added that is interfering with the form post behavior, this has left me really stumped :(

I have eliminated as many .js libraries as I could. Removed a bunch of old references to react and I am only including the basics - jquery, kendo, bootsrap, unobtrusive validation, bootbox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.ShortName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

which renders this:

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Affiliate Name must be a string with a maximum length of 150." data-val-length-max="150" data-val-required="The Affiliate Name field is required." id="AffiliateDomainModel_AffiliateName" maxlength="150" name="AffiliateDomainModel.AffiliateName" type="text" value="">
```

I expected the string "test" to be in the form collection. Instead I got

```
{test} count: 1
```

in the form collection. I confirmed that there is only one instance of my text box on the form.

Comment: Can you share the code of model class, view and controller action?

Comment: Hi Chetan, thanks for responding.  This turned out to be a silly problem (see my answer below).  There was nothing wrong with the form collection.  It just looked different when i was comparing side by side using different versions of visual studio which led me to think that had something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, disregard this post.  I missed adding a {get;set;} to one of my properties which is why the values were not binding to the view model.